How is latency handled in the BFF pattern? Looking for some examples
I'm seeking a practical approach/example to address latency concerns with the BFF pattern. While the definition suggests there's no increased latency with this pattern, I'm curious about how this is achieved and looking for insight into its internal implementation.

"While the definition suggests there's no increased latency with this pattern" - it depends on what latencies are compared. I would expect an increase of "single source" latency since you are introducing basically an extra hop, but overall page serve (in case of multiple data sources) should be reduced in general case. Can you please provide the definition you have used and it's source?

@GuruStron Definition source - https://blog.bitsrc.io/bff-pattern-backend-for-frontend-an-introduction-e4fa965128bf

I would argue that the definition provided by the linked article:

In a situation like this, we can use a BFF in order to shift some of this front-end logic to an intermediate layer. The intermediate layer is the BFF. When a frontend requests some data, it will call an API in the BFF.


The BFF will do the following.

Call the relevant microservices APIs and obtain the needed data
Format the data based on the frontend representation
Send the formatted data to the frontend


Does not allow to conclude that the latency is the same. By definition it will increase (of the single call for client-server communication), but the increase will be insignificant in most cases compared to the potential advantages.
The article basically states the same:

Now we know that a BFF is similar to a proxy server between the client and other external APIs, services, etc. If the request has to go through another component, it will definitely increase latency. However, the BFF latency is negligible compared to the browser’s high resource usage if it needs to work with multiple services not optimized for the frontend.


Building a BFF allows you to intelligently make batch calls to other backends/ microservices and return the data all at once, or return a more convenient representation by transforming and formatting the data.


This can be very useful for mobile clients on 2G or 3G networks where it can take seconds (or more) to establish the connection.

So while the latency of the single call can increase, the whole experience of using the app will improve (basically the "latency" of loading a page/screen which requires several request and/or less data then the original endpoint provides will improve compared to the case without BFF).
